# Do I need an Organization in my Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have inherited the management of some Google Cloud Platform "resources". My company has two projects, both of which are using some Google Maps APIs and one of which is using Firebase (outside developers are using these).

Would like to set up my Google Cloud instance "correctly" so we can grow. The developers don't really now which API keys they are using (or won't tell me) and they are unprotected. We are getting quota overages which I cannot track down.

I am thinking I should create one new project with new APIKeys that are secured. Give developers 1 week (at most) to migrate to these new keys, then remove or inactivate the old resources.

Reading the documentation I see the concept of an organization, the top node of a Google Cloud Platform instance. Seems like I should probably create an organization for our company, then make this one new Project under the Org and go from there.

But what is the point of an organization anyway? That is what I cannot find.

Comment: Hi bryan i think the best solution for you is create a new account where you can organize, and for me on my company we use firebase and for every project we have our own project on firebase, every project should have a project on firebase, that is for have a great domain for the time to use on any api you want..

Comment: you do not really need an organisation though but it might make things more structured, you could create a G Suite account and use the email to create the projects, thats would automatically create an organisation and each developer can  assigned a G suite email and invited to the Google cloud projects

Answer (score 2):

[“GCP users are not required to have an Organization resource. A user acquires an Organization resource only if they are also G Suite or Cloud Identity customers. ”](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#link-with-g-suite-or-cloud-id-accounts)
Organizations are kind of like Active directory but for GCP projects. You as the super admin can have control of all projects with one role. You can also view project billing data for all projects in one place. You can group related projects into folders. It allows for a great administrative advantage. It becomes more useful the more projects you have, as it allows you to be more organized. Lastly, the project belongs to the org, not the creator. So if the creator leaves, the project will remain in the org whereas normally it would be deleted. See the [Benefits of  the Organization resource](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#link-with-g-suite-or-cloud-id-accounts#benefits_of_the_organization_resource) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

[Benefits of the organization resource](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#benefits_of_the_organization_resource).
"With an organization resource, project resources belong to your organization instead of the employee who created the project. This means that the project resources are no longer deleted when an employee leaves the company; instead they will follow the organization resource's lifecycle on Google Cloud.

Furthermore, Organization Administrators have central control of all resources. They can view and manage all of your company's project resources. This enforcement means that there can no longer be shadow projects or rogue admins.

Also, you can grant roles at the organization level, which are inherited by all project and folder resource under the organization resource. For example, you can grant the Network Admin role to your networking team at the organization level, allowing them to manage all the networks in all project resources in your company, instead of granting them the role for all individual project resources."

"Google Cloud users are not required to have an organization resource, but some features of Resource Manager will not be usable without one" [Organizations](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#organizations)".

It is impossible for accounts associated with an organization resource to create project resources that aren't associated with an organization resource. [Organizations](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#organizations)"

Resource Manager features that are not available would include

- Organisation Policies
- Folders
- Moving Projects and Folders